# How to integrate node packages in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: node.js, codeigniter, npm, codeigniter-4

**How to integrate node packages in CodeIgniter 4?**

I build a web app with CodeIgniter 4 and I want to add some libraries.
I'm used to use npm with my JavaScript Web Apps and I'm wondering what is best practice to use npm with CodeIgniter 4.

1. Where do I initiate npm? In root or in /public/assets or somewhere else?
2. Once I installed a package (e.g. `npm install animate.css --save`) how do I reference the package in my app? Do I use `<link href="<?=base_url();?>/assets/node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
3. Once I deploy my app to production, do I deploy the node_modules as well?

Comment: I will suggest you not to deploy node_module in production, because node_module size will be more than your original project. keep node_module directory out of your project use gulp or laravel-wix copy these css and js file to your assets directory.

Comment: Thank you. Just for clarification: You suggest to install npm to the root, add larval-mix and let mix point to my node_modules folder? If I copy the css and js outside of the node_modules folder, why do I need laravel-mix or npm at all?

Comment: laravel-mix or npm you need compile you js, scss or css files. if you don't want to use this just simply copy and paste js, css file in you assets folder. advantage of using npm is with just 1 or 2 commands you can update and compile your assets with latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy node files in public/js
then call it in footer

call it here